# Recurring vba code buttons each with a different range but following a rule

Tags: excel, vba

I currently am using 2 tables on 2 different worksheets.

The first acts as a list of items while the second acts as an active sheet where an end user can research items and has a couple of possible interactions which are not relevant to the ends of the question.

Is there a way to use a part of the button name to compose the range i will use in the code?

In alternative, is there a smart way to make this scalable, possibly keeping 1 copy of the code and somehow depending on the button assign the ranges?

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim cb As Shape
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As Variant
        On Error Resume Next
If IsEmpty(Range("A2").Value) Then
MsgBox "Barcode appears to be empty!"
Exit Sub
Else
        If IsError(Range("E2").Value) Then
            MsgBox "Barcode appears to have no match!"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            y = (Range("J2").Value)
            If IsNumeric(y) Then
                x = Range("J2").Value
            Else
                MsgBox "Ammount to add/subtract must be a number!"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Set cb = ActiveSheet.Shapes("chkbx2")

            If cb.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
                If (Range("E2").Value - Range("J2").Value) < 0 Then
                    MsgBox "quantity can't go below 0"
                Else
                    Range(Range("M2")).Value = Range("E2").Value - Range("J2").Value
                    MsgBox "Subtracted " + x + " part(s) to component: " + CStr(Range("A2").Value)
                End If
            Else
                Range(Range("M2")).Value = Range("E2").Value + Range("J2").Value
                MsgBox "Added " + x + " part(s) to component: " + CStr(Range("A2").Value)
            End If
         End If
End If
End Sub
```

I left the full code for the macro just so that i am sure nothing is going to be missing.

My issue is this: i have 25 of these buttons currently in my sheet and i have found no way to "automate" the change in coordinates.
For example Button2_Click() -> uses coordinates on row2 like "A2", "E2", "J2"...  in the same way Button3_Click() "A3", "E3", "J3"...

Currently i manually wrote the code once per each button, which makes the project hard to escalate to bigger proportions.

Comment: application.caller will give you the button, from there you can use (a part of the name)

Comment: ah, thanks i was more than sure there would be a way to do so, but i was unable to track it down trough a quick Google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue and produce a working code instead of 25 instances of the same lines by using this:

```
Dim r As Variant
Dim v As Variant
v = Application.Caller
v = Replace(v, "Button ", "")

r = "A" & v
```

To generate all the ranges i need, thus changing the value contained inside r before each range so as to have the exact range i needed there, this successfully made the project easily scaleable.

**Note: an example of legal syntax using the variable to compose a range would be:**

this assumes you are calling this function trough an object named "Button x"
where x is a number

```
Sub Button_Click()

Dim r As Variant
Dim v As Variant

v = Application.Caller
v = Replace(v, "Button ", "")

r = "A" & v

If IsEmpty(Range(r).Value) Then
MsgBox "Cell appears to be empty!"
Exit Sub
Else
MsgBox "cell " + r + " contains " + Range(r).Value
End If

End Sub
```

- I used the cell notation made with letter+number clearly.
- I used 2 variables because i needed to compose multiple ranges and it allowed for a cleaner implementation
- I used variables of "variant" type thinking it neede to be compatible with different types of data in the code.

**Note: this also works for the checkbox i was talking about in the question**

in general this will help building a re-usable code that will be able to know where your data will be located depending on the name that was assigned to the button calling it, also assuming a naming convention is set and followed and that it's increment follows a rule in relation to the increment of the ranges.

Thanks [@EvR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8537807/evr) for the help tracking down the function that allowed me to proceed forward